# Дубли перекрестий (курсоров)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Создаю курсор(перекрестие) в matplotlib по событию в кнопке "btn"

```
 def cur(self):
     self.cursor = Cursor(self.ax, useblit=True, 
         color='magenta',linewidth=1)
************************************
self.btn.clicked.connect(self.cur)
```

Перекрестие создается, но если подвигать мышью создается много копий перекрестия. Далее, если мышь отодвинуть за пределы холста и вернуть в его пределы, то остается один курсор(перекрестие). Почему так происходит?